# viewstate in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

What are  the properties(of server control) that are stored in the ViewState in ASP.NET

Comment: i am not grammar guru, but this time lack of grammar makes your question obscure.

Comment: What ever it is that controls want to put in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

ViewState is a dictionary-type object that stores, by default, the state of all the controls in the markup of your page.  You can also programmatically add values to ViewState:

```
ViewState["MyStoredValue"] = 15;
```

You can use [page-level tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94c55d08.aspx) to inspect the contents of ViewState when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

if you say what are the properties that are stored then they are the ones that you have stored, if you are asking what can be stored then it can be anything that you can serialize.

You can store your value using Viewstate["variableName"]=value;

and you can retrieve back using variable=Viewstate["variableName"];